# Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done, kernel crashed with code 3221225477

Tags: python, jupyter

when i running gensim code to do some text mining, vscode jupyter crashed.
i've tried to search for solutions online for hours but still can't find a good method.
below is the conda env.

```
backcall                      0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache 1.6.4
certifi                       2022.6.15
colorama                      0.4.5
Cython                        0.29.28
debugpy                       1.6.0
decorator                     5.1.1
entrypoints                   0.4
gensim                        4.2.0
ipykernel                     5.5.0
ipython                       7.34.0
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
jedi                          0.17.2
jupyter-client                6.1.10
jupyter-core                  4.11.1
matplotlib-inline             0.1.3
nest-asyncio                  1.5.5
numpy                         1.21.6
packaging                     21.3
parso                         0.7.1
pickleshare                   0.7.5
pip                           22.1.2
prompt-toolkit                3.0.30
psutil                        5.9.1
Pygments                      2.12.0
pyparsing                     3.0.9
python-dateutil               2.8.2
pywin32                       304
pyzmq                         19.0.2
scipy                         1.7.3
setuptools                    63.4.2
six                           1.16.0
smart-open                    6.0.0
tornado                       6.2
traitlets                     4.3.3
wcwidth                       0.2.5
wheel                         0.37.1
wincertstore                  0.2
```

and jupyter log

```
error 10:30:28.238: Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: 3221225477, Reason: 
info 10:30:28.239: kill daemon
error 10:30:28.240: Raw kernel process exited code: 3221225477
error 10:30:28.245: Error in waiting for cell to complete [Error: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
    at t.KernelShellFutureHandler.dispose (c:\Users\xxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1002181843\out\extension.node.js:2:32353)
    at c:\Users\xxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1002181843\out\extension.node.js:2:51405
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at y._clearKernelState (c:\Users\xxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1002181843\out\extension.node.js:2:51390)
    at y.dispose (c:\Users\xxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1002181843\out\extension.node.js:2:44872)
    at c:\Users\xxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1002181843\out\extension.node.js:2:2320856
    at t.swallowExceptions (c:\Users\xxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1002181843\out\extension.node.js:7:118974)
    at dispose (c:\Users\xxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1002181843\out\extension.node.js:2:2320834)
    at t.RawSession.dispose (c:\Users\xxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1002181843\out\extension.node.js:2:2325771)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)]
warn 10:30:28.246: Cell completed with errors {
  message: 'Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done'
}
info 10:30:28.248: Cancel all remaining cells true || Error || undefined
info 10:30:28.248: Cancel pending cells
info 10:30:28.250: Cell 22 executed with state Error
```

uninstalled and installed pyzmq, traitlets, jupyter-client

Comment: I'd have to see the code, but this error showed up for me when I didn't copy a numpy array from a shared memory object.